# Востановить одну таблицу MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

Нужна помощь. Как можно сделать бэкап отдельной таблицы?

Есть сам файл бэкапа и есть работающая база данных в которой есть эта таблица до которой нужно откатится. Есть 2 базы данных. Нужно одну таблицу из первой БД перенести с заменой во вторую БД. Спасибо.

Первая БД HCDB вторая HCDB_KK. Нужно из БД HCDB_KK перекинуть таблицу dbo.mscApptChannels в БД HCDB. Пробовал:

```
Select *
into HCDB.dbo.mscApptChannels
From HCDB_KK.dbo.mscApptChannels
```

Выдало ошибку одинаковых имён. И при таком переносе, переносятся ли все ключи и триггеры?

---

[image: Инструкции SQL]

В SQL Server существует команда Задачи / Экспортировать данные. Но я застрял на запросе/инструкциях.Какие запросы там необходимо прописать?

Comment: ОС какакя ? Посмотрите на хабре https://habr.com/ru/post/105954/, тут через консоль. Или через клиент бд импортируй(н: DBeaver).

Comment: `select ... into .. from` создает таблицу с таким именем (поэтому и ругается). вам же надо просто данные вставить `insert into ... select ... from`, если не заботиться о целостности данных, и `truncate` для очистки

Comment: В мастере не переставляйте "галку" на `Использовать запрос`, тогда на следующей странице будет список таблиц - выбирайте нужную и в маппинге установите идентити инсерт включен, аппенд и предварительно удалить. Прошу прощения за русско-транслитную помесь - без понятия как в русскоязычном интерфейсе будут называться соответствующие кнопки/галки.